# iOS calendar covers control

Tags: iphone, delphi, firemonkey

While developing an app I managed to get around the virtual keyboard covering up the control being edited just nicely by using the appropriate events. However specifically on an iPhone opening up a calendar will cause the same problem as the virtual keyboard, with the difference that no proper event is fired. At that time there is no possibility to get the bounds of the date picker, so the date edit will potentially get covered up by the date picker and there seems to be nothing I can do about it. Again this is an iPhone issue, as the tablets open up a small panel near the date edit, and everyone is happy.

To clarify here is a comparison of the same app on an iPhone 6 and on an iPad.
[image]
[image]

How do I find the bounds of the calendar, in order to move other controls away from it?

Comment: I edited your question a bit, mostly adding an actual question! If that's not what you need to know, please edit, but stating the behaviour is different to asking a question. Do you want to know the calendar bounds? Do you want to know what the right event is? Etc. Also, when iPhone/iPad behavious is different re the panel, is that something you've coded or something inbuilt in the system? Some screenshots from both would help.

Comment: @DavidM: Thanks for the edit. Just added the screenshots. The calendar behavior is iOS standard - not coded by me. I hope that helps.

Comment: It does, but I don't know if I can help answer the question, sorry. Good luck!